# Next Js upgrade from 11 to 12 or 13

Tags: next.js, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing, next.js14

**Question 1** : I'm trying to upgrade the next js version for our custom application from 11.1.4 to 12.2.0
for this I'm getting the below mentioned issue

> error - ./node_modules/@internationalized/date/dist/import.mjs:1:0
>
> Module not found: Can't resolve
>
> '@swc/helpers/_/_class_private_field_init'

Import trace for requested module:

When I check this in some article they asked me to upgrade to next 13

**Question 2**: when I'm trying from next js 13 i'm getting the issue saying that

```
req.on is not a function
```

anyone come across the same issue and please suggest the solutions.

Thanks in advance !!

needs to upgrade the next js version from 11 to 12 or 13

Comment: Please search for errors before asking https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/48875#issuecomment-1592301037

Answer (score 0):

Check and update all dependencies for compatibility with Next.js 12.2.0 using **npm outdated**.

Delete your **node_modules** folder and **package-lock.json** file (rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json), then reinstall dependencies with **npm install**.

If problems persist, consider upgrading to Next.js 13 as it may resolve these compatibility issues.

Update your package.json to "^13.0.0" for Next.js and run **npm install**.

Next.js 13 Issue ("req.on is not a function"):
This error often arises from incorrect handling of API routes or custom server configurations in Next.js 13.

Review and adjust your API routes or custom server setup as per the Next.js 13 documentation.
Identify and refactor any middleware or server configurations that may be causing conflicts with the new version.
If using a custom server, consider switching to Next.js 13’s built-in server features for improved compatibility.